# What will be a complexity of min heap?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, min-heap

What will be a complexity of min heap in my case?

I need to figure out 5 smallest numbers in a list.

What I do is

```
public List<Integer> mins(final List<Integer> list) {
        final PriorityQueue<Integer> mins = new PriorityQueue<>(5, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        for (final int num: list) {
            if (mins.size() > 4) {
                if (mins.peek() > num) {
                    mins.poll();
                    mins.add(num);
                }
            } else {
                mins.add(num);
            }
        }
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(mins);
        Collections.sort(result);
        return result;
}
```

Is it correct that the complexity of the piece of code is O(nlog5) -> O(n)?
In many sources, I see that the complexity of Min Heap is nlog(n). Is it correct of the complexity of Min Heap is nlog(m) where m is a size of a heap?

Comment: A data structure doesnt have a complexity of its own, but operations on it do. In this case you are bth inserting into and removing from a heap.

Comment: To compound on what @user207421 mentions, there's different implemenations of heaps that have different time complexities for deletion / insertion as well. see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) for a few.

Comment: In your case, since the size is constant, operations on the heap would be constant.

Comment: No, but *log(M)* is, for one poll, assuming a binary heap.

Comment: And Nlog(M) for add() N times in queue of size M? If on each add() when size > M I poll() the an item?